# TSQL - Passing fields from table into stored procedure then storing result in temp table

Tags: t-sql, stored-procedures, temp-tables

I'm working with a client who has a stored procedure with about a dozen parameters.

I need to get the parameter values from tables in the database, then feed these into the stored procedure to get a number value.  I then need to join this value to a SELECT statement.

I know that I have to build a temp table in order to join the SP results with my select statement, but this is all new to me and could use some help.  Mostly focusing on how to feed field values into the SP. I would also like the Temp table to contain a couple of the parameters as fields so I can join it to my select statement.

any and all help is appreciated.

Thank You

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can capture the parameter values in declared variables.  Something like:

```
DECLARE @Parm1 int, @Parm2 varchar(50) -- Use appropriate names and datatypes

SELECT @Parm1 = Parm1ColumnName, @Parm2=Parm2ColumnName
FROM TableWithParmValues
-- Include a WHERE condition if appropriate

DECLARE @ProcOutput TABLE(outputvalue int) -- use appropriate names and datatypes to match output

INSERT @ProcOuptut
EXECUTE MyProc @ProcParm1 = @Parm1, @ProcParm2 = @Parm2 -- Use appropriate names
```

Then use the @ProcOutput temp table, and parameter variables as you need with your SELECT.

Comment: This is awesome.  Will I have to do some kind of loop to go through each set of column values, or will this code already do that?

Comment: The INSERT/EXECUTE will get all of the rows (from the first resultset) and place them into @ProcOutput, so you won't need a loop for that.  If you need to call your stored procedure multiple times, with multiple sets of parameters, then you will need a loop for that.

Answer (score 0):

*This is a comment that is better formatted as an answer.*

You don't need to create a temporary table, or table variable, to be able to join a numeric result with other data.  The following demonstrates various curiosities using `SELECT`s without explicitly creating any tables:

```
declare @Footy as VarChar(16) = 'soccer'
select * from (
  select 'a' as Thing, 42 as Thingosity
  union all
  select *
    from ( values ( 'b', 2 ), ( 'c', 3 ), ( @Footy, Len( @Footy ) ) ) as Placeholder ( Thing, Thingosity )
  ) as Ethel cross join
  ( select 42 as TheAnswer ) as Fred
```